# Encoding/charset associated to PHP strings

Tags: php, encoding, composer-php, specifications, built-in

The PHP documentation says:

> Of course, in order to be useful, functions that operate on text may have to make some assumptions about how the string is encoded. Unfortunately, there is much variation on this matter throughout PHP’s functions:
>
> [... a few special cases are described ...]
>
> Ultimately, this means writing correct programs using Unicode depends on carefully avoiding functions that will not work and that most likely will corrupt the data [...]

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

So naturally my question is: Where are these specifications that allow us to identify the encoding/charset associated to string arguments, return values, constants, array keys/values, ... for built-in functions/methods/data (e.g. `array_key_exists`, `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName`, `DateTime::format`, `$_GET[$key]`, `ini_set`, `PDO::__construct`, `json_decode`, `Exception::getMessage()` and many more)? How do composer package providers specify the encodings in which they accept/provide textual data?

I have been working roughly with the following heuristic: (1) never change the encoding of anything, (2) when forced to pick an encoding, pick UTF-8. This has been working for years but it feels very unsatisfactory.

Whenever I try to find an answer to the question, I only get search results relating to url encoding, HTML entities or explaining the interpretation of string literals (with the source file's encoding).

Comment: Why would you need specify encoding for `array_key_exists()` or `$_GET[$key]`? They're not doing any string manipulation, encoding is irrelevant.

Comment: @rob006 `php -r '$a = ["bla"]; var_dump([array_key_exists("\x30", $a), array_key_exists("\x00\x30", $a), array_key_exists("\x30\x00", $a), array_key_exists(mb_convert_encoding("\x00\x30", "UTF-8", "UTF-16"), $a)]);'` prints `[true, false, false true]`. All used keys are valid representation of zero in some encoding. If a URL parameter was encoded by the browser for an `input` field, you must know the encoding sent in the `Content-type` header alongside the form to safely access the value via `$_GET`. Real life example: https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ (utf-8 meta, latin-1 header, destroys code).

Comment: There is not really encoding involved in your example. It does not matter if `"\x00\x30"` is representation of `0` in some encoding, because string is just sequence of bytes - if you search for this particular sequence of bytes in array, you will find your respective value. You may try with `$a = ["\x00\x30" => "bla"]` as example - `"\x00\x30"` is just sequence of 2 bytes, and that is how PHP treats it. Encoding only matters if you want to convert bytes to characters, which is not the case for `array_key_exists()`.

Comment: Your example with `0` may be a little trickier because of type juggling, but AFAIK numbers are converted to string using ASCII, so `0` is `"\x30"`.

Comment: @rob006 The real problem is: does anyone know resources/strategies that allow us to stop working on a "AFAIK" basis? I know about PHP's byte-array-like concept of strings and finding examples where this works as expected really isn't hard.

Comment: The only thing that can generally be said about string strategies in PHP is that if you don't *do* anything with strings, i.e. you just read them from somewhere and write them to somewhere, you do not need to be aware of encodings at all. As soon as you try to *manipulate* strings, you need to think about them in terms of encoded characters, and carefully study the functions that you apply to them. The array key example above is a red herring in this discussion, as that has additional complications in how exactly numeric-ish array keys are interpreted.

Comment: TL;DR: You need to be conscious of details all along the way, be it encoding related or type-juggling related or array related. There's no simple golden rule. Yes, that sucks.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in PHP are what other languages would call *byte arrays*, i.e. purely a raw sequence of bytes. PHP is not generally interested in what characters those bytes represent, they're just bytes. Only functions that need to work with strings on a *character* level need to be aware of the encoding, anything else doesn't.

For example, `array_key_exists` doesn't need to know anything about characters to figure out whether a key with the same bytes as the given string exists in an array.

However, `mb_strlen` for example explicitly tells you how many *characters* the string consists of, so it needs to interpret the given string in a specific encoding to give you the right number of characters. `mb_strlen('漢字', 'latin1')` and `mb_strlen('漢字', 'utf-8')` give very different results. There isn't a unified way how these kinds of functions are made encoding aware*, you will need to consult their manual entries.

* The `mb_` functions in particular generally use `mb_internal_encoding()`, but other sets of functions won't.

Functions like `DateTime::format` are looking for specific characters in the format string to replace by date values, e.g. `d` for the day, `m` for the month etc. You can generally assume that these are ASCII byte values it's looking for, unless specified otherwise (and I'm not aware of anything that specifies otherwise). So any ASCII compatible encoding will usually do.

For a lot more details, you may be interested in [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Answer (score 0):

Often this can be found in the official documentation, e.g., the `DOMDocument` class has a property `encoding` (determined by XML declaration). As for methods that return strings, I recommend reading [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151293/how-does-php-internally-represent-strings)

Comment: What do you expect this to print: `php -r '$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-1"); $dom->loadXML("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?><b\xFC />"); var_dump($dom->getElementsByTagName("b\xFC")->length); var_dump($dom->getElementsByTagName("b\xC3\xBC")->length);'`